# Fortran IO lock / nesting print statements

Tags: fortran

I have a simple program that should print the return value of a function.
If the function contains a print statement, the program never terminates.
Is this some kind of IO lock, generated from the outer print, that prevents the print inside the function to complete?

```
program print
  implicit none
  print *, func()
contains
  function func() result(res)
    integer   :: res
    res = 3
    print *, "jojo"
  end function
end program
```

Comment: The program does recursive IO  This is not permitted - see 9.11p2 and p3 of F2003 or 9.12p2 of F2008.

Comment: Is there a compiler flag, that detects this?

Comment: That will depend on your compiler, but I know (IIRC) that nagfor does detect this at runtime by default and error terminates.  Others may too with/without options.  Detecting at compile time, on the other hand...